# AngularJS binding inputs and table for various behavior

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and some check boxes and radio buttons. Each cell of the table contains data like so:

```
<td>
  <div id="Person">John</div>
  <div id="City">Paris</div>
  <div id="FavFood">Cheese</div>
  <div id="Pet">Cat</div>
</td>
```

The check boxes' names are: Person, Location, FavFood and Pet (one for each div in the cells). Multiple check boxes can be clicked and the corresponding divs get displayed. The data corresponding to the unchecked check boxes is hidden.

The radio buttons have the same names (one for each div in the cells). When a radio button is selected, the table cells' background gets colored depending on the value in the corresponsing div.

Example:

**checked box**: Person and Pet (the data in these divs gets displayed)

**checked radio button**: Pet (cells with the same Pet will have the same color. The colors are the 7 colors of the rainbow predefined in an array in javascript. They are attributed to the Pets in alphabetical order: Cat (red), Dog (orange), Parrot (yellow).

```
<td style="background-color:red">
  <div id="Person"  style="display:block">John</div>
  <div id="City"    style="display:none">Paris</div>
  <div id="FavFood" style="display:none">Cheese</div>
  <div id="Pet"     style="display:block">Cat</div>
</td>
```

I have this currently implemented in javascript using onClick and a lot of DOM manipulation by ids and child elements. I get all the data in a json from an API.

**Can I simplify this with AngularJS?**

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve, because I have the feeling you're really not doing it the way you should do it (i.e. by just using bunding, and modifying the model instead of manipulating the DOM). What are those items that you want to color? When is an item checked? Why do you display an empty radio button, which doesn't even have a name and isn't bound to anything? What's the link betwee an action and an item to color?

Comment: Yes, I don't think I'm solving this the right way. I'm remaking this using ng-style (found out about it right after posting this question). I want to color the labels whose radio buttons are checked. The names of the checked radio buttons are passed through a cookie.

Comment: If you still need help, I'd be happy to help, but I'd need answers to my questions.

Comment: I've edited my post to expose the bigger task.